# How to use a CSS class with an icon class in an <a> tag

Tags: html, css, hover, icons, visual-web-developer

I want to use a GitHub icon which should show some text when hovered over. But using a CSS class with an icon class is showing no progress.
Here is the code for reference:

```css
/* Tooltip container */

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a class="tooltip fab fa-github" style="font-size: 2em;" href='https://github.com/rohitthapliyal2000'> </a> <span class="tooltiptext">Hovered text</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your markup, you could use the *adjacent sibling combinator* ([**`+`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)) in your selectors - see demo below:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  text-decoration: none; /* remove anchor underline */
}

.tooltip + .tooltiptext { /* <- note the + combinator */
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tooltip:hover + .tooltiptext { /* <- note the + combinator */
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">

<a class="tooltip fab fa-github" style="font-size: 2em;" href='https://github.com/rohitthapliyal2000'></a>
<span class="tooltiptext">Hovered text</span>
```

Comment: The code is working fine when using a single icon. But I have a list of icons. This list uses a different CSS, and a container class as well.
Because of this, the icon is not visible and the hovering is not working.
Can you please look that up?
`code
.container {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
#links {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#links ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#links ul li {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

<section id='links' class='container'>
      <ul>
`

Comment: Can you please see what's the problem over here?
[https://jsfiddle.net/tbzj479v/]

Comment: @RohitThapliyal I have seen the above fiddle, can you explain the problem?

Comment: Please see, the Github icon is not working by hovering.
Plus, it is hidden, idk why?

Comment: Please see this full code of mine: https://jsfiddle.net/tbzj479v/
This isn't working as expected.
Thank you.

Comment: @RohitThapliyal I guess its the same fiddle you shared previously, are you sure you have updated the fiddle? I see [this](https://imgur.com/Cm5oPPW) again...

Comment: @RohitThapliyal there is a `tooltip` class defined - you can see this if you inspect element - use another class, say `my-tooltip`...

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally worked. Can you please tell what the problem was?

Comment: @RohitThapliyal I've already dropped a hint why it didn't work, that would be for you to find; try inspecting element :)

Answer (score 2):

`.tooltiptext` should be a child of `.tooltip`

```html
<a class="tooltip fab fa-github" style="font-size: 2em;" href='https://github.com/rohitthapliyal2000'>
  <span class="tooltiptext">Hovered text</span>
</a>
```